# how to read values in the column of a table in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

There is a table called Friends. It has columns named Names, Address, Phone no, Dob. We want to use Names which are in Friends table one by one. so I want to store all names in an array which is to be used later.

Comment: Let's work on our tagging, okay? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229784/tips-for-effectively-tagging-questions

Comment: Also: what language are you using to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the rundown:

In your .config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=[server name here];Initial Catalog=[db name here];User Name=blah;Password=blah"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In your code:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

...

// In ASP.NET use WebConfigurationManager instead...
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Friends ORDER BY Name", connection);

List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        nameList.Add(reader["Name"] as string);
    }
}
string[] names = nameList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the top result from googling

```
 get sql data c#
```

http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=454

The SQL statement you want is

```
 select * from friends
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name FROM Friends ORDER BY Name
```